# Would a comment have been removed for trying to get a user's attention?

Tags: discussion, comments, delete

Today, I posted a comment (comment #0) to a user's answer (I know which user,

but I'm not revealing it in case that should be private) in an attempt to bring that user's

attention to a specific pair of other comments that I had made (comments #1 and #2).

More recently, when I looked at where I had posted comment #0, it wasn't there any more.

I then checked my activity, and it didn't have any record of the comment

(which, I believe, is what happens when comments get deleted).

Would comment #0 in fact have been deleted due to just trying

to bring a user's attention to comments elsewhere on this site?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I deleted the comment, because at best it was not on topic or proper use of comments (the new answer you commented on had nothing to do with the discussion you linked to apart from involving the same user), and at worst it was badgering. When you post a comment on somebody's answer, they are automatically notified, so the user was aware of your previous comments and could address them if he wanted to/had time. If you really want to bring someone's attention to a question or discussion then most of the active users on the site (including the one your were commenting on) use their real names and link to their websites where you can find their emails. Try using that method, but again watch out for badgering.